# How do I deploy multiple war files on Tomcat through shell on remote servers at a time?

Tags: java, linux, shell, tomcat7

We have builds run on one of the servers and we copy the war to 5 remote servers individually and ssh to those boxes and deploy the wars manually. I am looking for a way where we could deploy all the 5 war files at time through running a shell script??

```
 scp 123.war xyzserver:~/.
 ssh xyzserver -t “
 sudo su
 sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop
 rm -fr /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/123*  
 cp ./xyz.war /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ 
 sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start” 
 exit
```

Does some thing like this work? I am not sure whether cp would wait until the tomcat stops? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the servers you could run a process on sudo cron that would watch a directory for war files and execute the commands to stop Tomcat, undeploy, deploy, and start Tomcat.  Then you could just script the scp to the "watched" folder.

On the servers create a bash script to check for files:

```
if [ "$(ls -A ${WATCHED_DIR})" ]; then
    /etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop
    rm -fr /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/${WEBAPP_NAME}
    mv ${WATCHED_DIR}/${WEBAPP_NAME}.war /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/
    chown -R tomcat:tomcat /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/${WEBAPP_NAME}
    /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
fi
```

Add this to the sudo crontab so it runs as root

On the client side (where the war file was generated), create a script that just copies the files to that directory on the server

```
scp ${WEBAPP_NAME}.war server1:${WATCHED_DIR}
scp ${WEBAPP_NAME}.war server2:${WATCHED_DIR}
scp ${WEBAPP_NAME}.war server3:${WATCHED_DIR}
scp ${WEBAPP_NAME}.war server4:${WATCHED_DIR}
scp ${WEBAPP_NAME}.war server5:${WATCHED_DIR}
```

Comment: ---Could you explain it more detailed?? I didn't get you

Comment: On each of the servers create a bash/shell script that checks a folder on the server for war files and if there are any, will stop tomcat, remove the current webapp, move the new war file to the webapp folder, and start tomcat.  Add this to the sudo crontab so that it will run as root ever minute.  Then on the client side, make a separate shell script that runs the scp command to push the new war to each of the servers under the folder being watched by the server-side script running under sudo's crontab.

Comment: Wow..That seems to be a good solutions .Thanks @Brian Harman. Let me me try this out